# ng-bind for title tag goes outside of the element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7, ng-bind

ng-bind used for the title tag inside the header behaves weird. This is my code:

```
<title page-title ng-bind="page_title"></title>
```

and here's the output:

```
My Page Sucks
<title page-title="" ng-bind="page_title" class="ng-binding"></title>
```

it goes outside instead of inside the title tag

here's a snippet of the pageTitle directive:

```
streamViewApp
// page title
.directive('pageTitle', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function() {
                var listener = function(event, toState) {

                    var name = ($rootScope.site_settings) ? (($rootScope.site_settings[0] != undefined) ? $rootScope.site_settings[0]  : 'StreamView' ): 'StreamView';

                    var default_title = name.value;

                    $timeout(function() {
                        $rootScope.page_title = (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle)
                            ? default_title + ' - ' + toState.data.pageTitle : default_title;
                    });
                };
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

UPDATE:

Works well when called within the body tag, weird thing happens when called in head

```
<body><title page-title="" ng-bind="page_title" class="ng-binding">My Page Sucks</title>
```

Comment: What do you want to do and could you show the `pageTitle` directive?

Comment: @Raxel21 added additional info :)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: @Phix sure, kindly check. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ng-bind` define the pagetitle as custom data with router state.

```
state('customerdata', {
        url: '/viewcustomer',
        templateUrl: '/components/customers.html',
        controller: 'customerdatacntrl',
        controllerAs: 'self',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Customer Data'     <--- Notice here
        }
```

Then in directive you can get hold of `toState` object and set the next page title from there.

```
return {
      link: function (scope, element) {    
        var listener = function (event, toState) {

          var pageTitle;
          if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) {
            pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle;
          }

          $timeout(function () {
            element.text(pageTitle);
          }, 0, false);
        };

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
      }
};
```

Comment: I am sorry but we cannot alter the ng-bind usage since it is widely used on our system and other systems as well. The main prob is why does the title being appended before the actual element who's calling it all of a sudden, because this worked well before. Thanks anyway